# No view found for id 0x7f0800c4 for fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, child-fragment

I get this error when I am trying to replace the parent fragment (`SearchFragment`) from the child fragment (`ClassroomsTab`) in a swipe tab `viewPager`. Basically what I am trying to achieve is have a swipe tab menu with multiple buttons in each child fragment that closes the swipe tab menu and open a different existing fragment. The `SearchFragment` is in a Navigation Drawer activity and so is the destination fragment of the buttons.

From what I have read, a solution to this issue is to replace the `getChildFragmentManager()` in this line of code: `viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));` with `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` or `getFragmentManager()`. This solves the issue of the app crashing, but when I click back on the search tab through the navigation drawer from the new fragment, most of the swipe tab child fragments with the buttons don't show up.

Thanks for the help :)

`SearchFragment` `OnCreateView` code:

```
public TabLayout tabLayout;
    public ViewPager viewPager;
    public static int int_items = 5;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //this inflates the tab layout file.
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_layout,null);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));  

        // this puts the titles on the top
        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        });
        //this preloads the other tabs. currently only have it set to one for testing
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);

        return view;

    }
```

`ClassroomsTab` code (with only one button for now while I'm testing):

note: `content_frame` is the framelayout of the navigation activity

```
public class ClassroomsTab extends Fragment {
View myView;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.classrooms, container, false);
    defineButtons();
    return myView;
}
public void defineButtons() {
    Button CR1C1 = (Button)myView.findViewById(R.id.CR1C1);
    CR1C1.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);

}
private View.OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        FragmentManager fragmentmanager = getFragmentManager();
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.CR1C1:
                fragmentmanager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame
                                ,new MapFragment())
                        .commit();
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Full error

> 09-08 15:52:13.154 12220-12220/com.example.jeremy.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.jeremy.app, PID: 12220
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0800c4 (com.example.jeremy.app:id/content_frame) for fragment MapFragment{c7d968f #2 id=0x7f0800c4}
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1417)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1754)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1822)
>           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2591)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2378)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2333)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2240)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:703)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Comment: You probably don't have `R.id.content_frame` as your Fragment container in your activity. Please check your Activity layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when you change the layouts in several transactions.
the same happened to me and I solved it by clearing the stack behind it. but you have to use a single `FragmentManager`for all of your transactions.
put this code after you done the transaction

```
    private void clearStack() {
    if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount(); i++) {
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
        }
    }

    if (fragmentManager.getFragments().size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < fragmentManager.getFragments().size(); i++) {
            Fragment mFragment = fragmentManager.getFragments().get(i);
            if (mFragment != null) {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(mFragment).commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, this code works perfectly form the tests I've done so far. After looking through the code, I was wondering if it is possible to simplify this code or if everything included is necessary? dont worry about including code, but it would be great to have an answer :)

Comment: where can i call this method..i have same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56147086/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-no-view-found-for-id-0x7f0904b3-com-my-app