# problem in setup view pager(have recycler) in dialog android

Tags: android, dialog, android-viewpager

I want to setup view pager in full screen dialog.
view pager have recyclerview.
I wrote adapter and model for recyclerview that is completed.
when dialog want to start I get error and my application give force close
my code is here:

dialog xml: 
some thing

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager_ranking"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/layout_user_rank"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout_ranking"/>
some thing
```

and this is my code for dialog

```
public class RankingDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public static String TAG = "RankingDialog";

    ImageView exit;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    RankViewPagerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL , R.style.FullScreenDialogStyle);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.winners_ranking_dialog , container , false);

        init(view);

        exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        adapter = new RankViewPagerAdapter(App.ACTIVITY.getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        return view;
    }

    private void init(View view){
        exit = view.findViewById(R.id.exit_ranking);
        tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout_ranking);
        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_ranking);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Dialog dialog = getDialog();
        if (dialog != null){
            int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width , height);
        }
    }
}
```

i get this wrong and force close my application in android studio:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ir.doroste.doroste, PID: 2689
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0900f7 (ir.doroste.doroste:id/view_pager_ranking) for fragment RankingFragment{be94a1c #1 id=0x7f0900f7 android:switcher:2131296503:0}
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1454)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2243)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:654)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:146)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21045)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21045)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6459)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21045)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6459)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21045)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6459)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:849)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21045)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2576)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1635)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1886)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1515)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7091)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:638)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
Application terminated.
```

and my code in winners ranking dialog :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/exit_ranking"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/normal_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_exit"
        android:tint="@color/colorWhite"/>

    <customControls.CustomTextViewBold
        android:id="@+id/ranking_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/normal_margin"
        android:text="ranking"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/large_font" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout_ranking"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/ranking_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/normal_margin"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/tab_text" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/circle_rank"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_home" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/large_margin"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/wave_home" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/large_margin"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/mounte" />


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager_ranking"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/layout_user_rank"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout_ranking" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_user_rank"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:padding="@dimen/normal_margin">

        <customControls.CustomTextViewBold
            android:id="@+id/user_rank"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="356"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="@dimen/normal_font" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_avatar_rank"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/normal_margin"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/user_rank"
            android:src="@drawable/avatar" />

        <customControls.CustomTextViewBold
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/large_margin"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/user_avatar_rank"
            android:text="meyti_dy"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="@dimen/normal_font" />

        <customControls.CustomTextViewBold
            android:id="@+id/toman_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="price"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="@dimen/normal_font" />

        <customControls.CustomTextViewBold
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toman_id"
            android:text="20000"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="@dimen/normal_font" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure the ViewPager with id R.id.view_pager_ranking is contained within the layout file R.layout.winners_ranking_dialog?

Comment: @chips yes sir. this is amazing error :)

Comment: Please share R.layout.winners_ranking_dialog layout. I guess you have missed something on it.

Comment: @SultanMahmud  i add R.layout.winners_ranking_dialog layout to end of my question.

Comment: try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJG5ZuZtPKY and this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DbiyoWjQD38 and maybe you find your solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508044/android-fragment-no-view-found-for-id/29908804 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52231981/no-view-found-for-id-0x7f0800c4-for-fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
adapter = new RankViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```